# htaccess rewrite url php / Godaddy / Linux Hosting

Tags: php, .htaccess

I know that there are too many questions and answers about this so i have to apologize in advanced but nothing works for me.

I lunched my website in Godaddy/Linux Hosting and trying to apply a rewrite for my urls. What it looks like now is

https://www.mywebsite.com/tours/tour_id=15

and i would like it ot be

https://www.mywebsite.com/tour/15 or even better insted of the ID to GET the title from the sql (which if is not possible through htaccess i can do it with php) My Own Title https://www.mywebsite.com/tour/My Own Title

I am really new in htaccess, below is what is already written in the file

```
# Redirects to https
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mywebsite\.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.mywebsite.com/$1  [R=301,L]

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Removes index.php from ExpressionEngine URLs
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^GET.*index\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/system/.* [NC]
RewriteRule (.*?)index\.php/*(.*) /$1$2 [R=301,NE,L]

# Directs all EE web requests through the site index file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]

# Remove trailing slash in the end
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]
```

I would be grateful for any help

Answer (score 0):

Add to top of .htaccess this rewrite rule:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^tour\/\d+$ /tours/tour_id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Just did it... is not working. It should work instantly, correct?